# Node js couchbase counter function binding issue on Mac Os X

Tags: node.js, macos, couchbase

I am trying to do some things with Node.js and couchbase, and am using the SDK from [here](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/node-2.0/introduction.html).

However, I am encountering issues with running the 'counter' method on a bucket.
I'm running Mac Os X 10.9.5 and use [couchbase v2.0.5](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/node-2.0/introduction.html)

This is my test program:

```
var couchbase = require('couchbase');
var connection = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://myhostname'); 
var bucket = connection.openBucket();

bucket.counter('test', 1, {initial:1}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});
```

When I want to run this, I get issues with the binding, so it seems:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ntohll
    Referenced from: <somepath>/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node
    Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _ntohll
    Referenced from: <somepath>/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node
    Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Other methods such as insert, upsert, get, ... work perfectly, but the 'counter' method is giving me this particular issue.

Any ideas on how to resolve this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, when doing this on Mac Os X 10.10, the library works without a problem.
On 10.9.5 it gives this particular problem.

I managed to resolve the issue myself.
For reference: how I solved this on Mac OS X 10.9

In `node_modules/couchbase/deps/lcb/gyp_config/mac/x64/config.h` , I removed the following lines of code:

```
/* Have ntohll */
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define HAVE_HTONLL
```

After running a manual node-gyp install, everything worked like a charm

```
cd node_modules/couchbase
node-gyp install && node-gyp build
```

If you don't have node-gyp, you can install it using

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Comment: A fix should be released soon, see https://forums.couchbase.com/t/error-on-counter-function-in-node-js-library-on-mac-os-x/2915/4

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer. I would change the node-gyp to : node-gyp install && node-gyp build. so noobs like me don't stumble upon it :)